# Formatting system date, and comparing error

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I have a String called `yourDate` `2012-11-30`. Now i need to compare this date with the system date to check if it has **exceeded or equaled** the system date.

How can i do this ?

My approach;

var tDay= Ext.Date.parse("2012-11-30", "Y-m-d");
    var sDay= new Date().dateformat('Y-m-d'); // system date

I get an error message `TypeError: (new Date).dateformat is not a function`. How can i correct this ?

note: I am using Extjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var sDay = Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d')
```

But I don't think you need to format your **current** date for comparison.

You can just use `var sDay = new Date()` and then compare date objects like `if(sDay > tDay)`